# How can I pass two args from timer.publish properties to any method Swift/Combine

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, timer, combine

I have timer method where it get called whenever new instance is created. I want every ticker should be stored in dictionary with respect to each instance like **[test1: 1, test2: 1] , [test1: 2, test2: 2] ...**...So on. Tried below option but not able to send any values. Currently with .scan I am able to send only integer

```
var subscriptions = Set()
var dict = NSMutableDictionary()

func multiplecall(name: String) {
Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
.autoconnect()
.scan(1) { value, _ in value + 1 }
.sink(receiveValue: fetchValues)
.store(in: &subscriptions)
}

func fetchValues(ticker: Int){
print(ticker)

}



**Expecting something like this**
    func fetchValues(testName: String, ticker: Int){
    dict[testName] = ticker
    }

multiplecall(name: "test1")
multiplecall(name: "test2")
```

Comment: You do realise what kind of function `sink` should take as a parameter, right?

Comment: @Sweeper is it takes only integer type? Sorry don't know I am new to combine

Comment: How about just doing `.sink { fetchValues(testName: name, ticker: $0) }`? Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Sweeper, getting error "Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure". I tried these combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything super special here. Instead of passing `fetchValues` to `sink`, pass a closure:

```
.sink(receiveValue: { value in
    fetchValues(testName: name, ticker: value)
})
```

or simply:

```
.sink { value in
    fetchValues(testName: name, ticker: value)
}
```

Here is a complete code that prints the dictionary after publishing the first 5 values:

```
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
var dict = [String: Int]()

func multiplecall(name: String) {
Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
    .scan(1) { value, _ in value + 1 }
    .prefix(5)
    .sink { _ in
        print(dict)
    } receiveValue: { value in
        fetchValues(testName: name, ticker: value)
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
}

func fetchValues(testName: String, ticker: Int){
    dict[testName] = ticker
}

multiplecall(name: "test1")
multiplecall(name: "test2")
```

Output:

```
["test1": 6, "test2": 5]
["test1": 6, "test2": 6]
```

Note that the first line is produced from the first publisher completing. At this point `test2` has not completed yet. That's why it's `"test2": 5`.

Comment: passing closure to a function, cool